# How to change the HTTP port number of JBoss 7 dynamically

Tags: batch-file, jboss, jboss7.x

I have grouped my Jboss 7 server, Postgres database and test.bat into a demo.exe file using Advanced Installer. When  file i.e demo.exe file double clicked on the client side then test.bat file runs and  it deploys  JBoss and postgres at the predefined location and the service starts and my application runs at the port number 8080 .All the script has been written to test.bat file .This demo.exe file has to used by different users . It may be possible that 8080 might be used or engaged by different application on client side.

So how can i change port number of jboss dynamically on the client side as per port usage?
Do i have to use any Jboss installer or write scipt on batch file i.e test.bat ?
Not able to click things or right approach  :(

Any help will be highly appreciated and will be thankful .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using `CLI`. This example changes the port from 8081 to 8080:

Start CLI (in `.../bin/`):

```
$ ./jboss-cli.sh   
You are disconnected at the moment. Type 'connect' to connect to the server or 'help' for the list of supported commands.
```

Connect

```
[disconnected /] connect
```

Change into the target area

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] cd /socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/socket-binding=http
```

Show the current state:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 socket-binding=http] ls -l  
ATTRIBUTE         VALUE     TYPE      
bound             true      BOOLEAN   
bound-address     127.0.0.1 STRING    
bound-port        8081      INT       
client-mappings   undefined LIST      
fixed-port        false     BOOLEAN   
interface         undefined STRING    
multicast-address undefined STRING    
multicast-port    undefined INT       
name              http      STRING    
port              8081      INT
```

Change the port attribute:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 socket-binding=http] :write-attribute(name="port", value="8080")  
{  
    "outcome" => "success",  
    "response-headers" => {  
        "operation-requires-reload" => true,  
        "process-state" => "reload-required"  
    }  
}
```

Note that the process-state is "reload-required"

Look again:

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 socket-binding=http] ls -l                                        
ATTRIBUTE         VALUE     TYPE      
bound             true      BOOLEAN   
bound-address     127.0.0.1 STRING    
bound-port        8081      INT       
client-mappings   undefined LIST      
fixed-port        false     BOOLEAN   
interface         undefined STRING    
multicast-address undefined STRING    
multicast-port    undefined INT       
name              http      STRING    
port              8080      INT
```

Note that here as well the `bound-port` is still at the old value.

So go back to the root directory

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 subsystem=web] cd /
```

Reload

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] :reload  
{  
    "outcome" => "success",  
    "response-headers" => {"process-state" => "reload-required"}  
}
```

That means that the reload is still in progress, again

```
[standalone@localhost:9999 /] :reload  
{"outcome" => "success"}
```

Now the HTTP connector should listen on the new port.

*Update*

The question asks for changing the port *dynamically* (JBoss is up and running).
The other option is to write the port into the configuration file (`standalone.xml`). This is *statically*, but it will probably work as well as for installation purposes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  i have some following doubts :-

1.Suppose if i'm successful in changing the port number e.g 8080 to 8081 then even it is also not sure that 8081 port number is free.
2.As of now , users are using http://localhost:8080 to start the application then how would a user a know that he/she has to use another port if 8080 is engaged?
3.Is it possible that we can give a port number at command propmpt if the specified port i.e 8080 is busy and contitue with the start jboss process?

Comment: You are using an installer, if I see this correctly. So yes, you should be able to prompt for a port, to check that no other process is listening on that port, and even launch a browser at the end of the installation with a given URL that matches the port. I do not know "Advanced Installer", so possibly ask another question on how to achieve this using this (or any other) installation generator tool. During the installation each one may use the script in this answer to change the port *dynamically*.

Comment: Yes, i'm using Advanced installer but even i'm not having much knowledge of it. Can u please tell me any good installer that can help me to solve my question  i.e where i can configure the post number?

1 thing more ... as port number is defined in standalone.xml so cant we add few more port numbers into the standalone file so that dynamically it can check and switch to unused port?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. Just try it (writing a script for any installer), and post another question. I would check for the next free port (starting at 8080), and suggest that one during installation. If the user hits OK, configure JBoss accordingly.

Comment: Thanx Beryllium for your time and effort :) ......... if you find solution of it then kindly post here :)